Issue connecting a discord.py bot to a google sheet
I've been trying to connect a discord bot to a google sheet. I am using the library google.oauth2 and import service_account from that
from google.oauth2 import service_account

My issue comes from the initialization of the sheet. I have the following function that is called when the sheet has not already been initialized.
def init_sheet(cls):
    creds = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(CREDS, scopes=SCOPES) 
    service = discovery.build("sheets", "v4", credentials=creds)
    cls.sheet = service.spreadsheets()` 

When this is checked in cmd I get an error saying
pyasn1.error.UnsupportedSubstrateError: Cannot convert str to a seekable bit stream.

I was given this code by the creator of the bot and am taking over from them. I've talked to them and they said that this was not an error that they encountered. I am using the google cloud api services to link both the bot and the sheet together. The credentials are correct and the scope is
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets']


I recommend using gspread for high level interactions with the sheet. The main problem you are getting pyasn1.error is probably unrelated and needs more data to understand what's going on as it's not a direct cause from spreadsheets api.
Go to your Google Developer Page enable Sheets API. Than try this code which is written with gspread:
import gspread
from google.oauth2.service_account import Credentials

SCOPES = ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets"]

creds = Credentials.from_service_account_file('creds.json', scopes=SCOPES)
client = gspread.authorize(creds)
sheet_id = "YourSheetId"

sheet = client.open_by_key(sheet_id)

values_list = sheet.sheet1.row_values(1) #Get the first row values
print(values_list)

Of course don't forget you have to install gspread:

pip install gspread

For more info about how to use gspread visit their starter page.
One last thing to note. Add the service_account email as a creator for your sheet so it has access. You can find the service_account email here. It should be under "Credentials">"Service Accounts" tab. Just copy the email you see there.
